# Using PCIe risers, how many GPUs can fit on one motherboard and what power supply would it require?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, bitcoin

I'm going to make my own mining rig for bitcoins. I have a friend who's going to build me a custom casing for it so it will be open air. Now what I want to know is how many GPUs can be crammed onto one motherboard such as this one: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157262
Additionally, I'm looking maybe for an alternative to this motherboard to put 5870s in bulk.(Socket could be anything really, AMD only as they have cheap CPUs though)

I currently have a 5850 in my everyday computer which I use for mining, it's clocked at 950mhz core clock up from 725mhz and the memory is at 350mhz down from 1000mhz.

That being said, I would be looking for putting 6 5870s total, each clocked at 1100mhz up from 850mhz and memory at 160mhz down from 1200mhz.

what kind of PSU would be able to handle all of that? (No hard drive, just a flash drive)

Also what PCIe slots can we plug in risers to?3

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: I had not seen the link to his other questions, the Asus P6T6 looks promising and I might just go with that, more expensive than I had planned but oh well

Comment: For that amount of money, you may just look into the new ASIC stations that are coming out. Much smaller footprint and much greater throughput.

Comment: BFL will not deliver, and the pre-order wait list is just long as hell..

Comment: What is your hash rate? it may be cheeper to buy [ASICs](https://products.butterflylabs.com/). $149.00 will get you 4.5 GHash/sec (the highest I saw was 0.879 GHash/sec for one card, so unless you can buy the cards for cheeper than $29/card the ASIC is cheeper in $/(GHash/sec))

Comment: The only ASICs that have shipped yet is the Avalon ones (Like what 50 of them? something like that) The BFL Jalapeno will never be shipped, and before I have the chance to even touch one, the whole pre-order list will have gotten them. Bitcoin mining at the moment is still owned by GPUs, mainstream ASICs are a myth, they are still a long way from here, BFL has delayed shipping by 6 months already

Answer (score 0):

That motherboard has three usable slots (the 3 PCI Express 2.0 slots). There are no (reasonable) graphics cards for the PCIe x1 or PCI slots. You will want a powerful (and efficient) power supply to power all of the cards. Probably something 700W 80Plus Bronze or better.

Also there is a new [Bitcoin StackExchange site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) you may want to check out.

Comment: I'm looking at the Asus P6T6 right now, which has 6 PCIe slots, so what power supplies can work with 6 cards?

Comment: You will definitely want 1000W or greater. Also make sure it has enough cables.

Answer (score 0):

each 5870 uses 2 places because the card is so thick.  4 GPU's is the most I have ever heard of in a system.  Even that is going to require at least 1000w if not 1200w PSU.  You may have have to have 2 power supplies.  If you manage to find a motherboard that can fit 6 you will almost definitely need 2 power supplies.  You will need pci express 2.0 and all need (x16) slots.

You can have 3 ati radeon 5870 in that mobo.  Because of the bandwidth required a riser is a terrible idea.  Also this thing is going to be crazy loud under load.  You would be better off buying 3 dual cards.  If my memory is correct the 5970 is the dual version.

Comment: 1x is more than enough for hashing so risers even with a big loss of performance wouldn't matter really.